# Adding a quadratic variable to regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics

In my textbook I often see a quadratic term in the regression. For example let's say I have the regression model: $\log(\mathrm{wage})=\beta_0+\beta_1\mathrm{educ}+\beta_2\mathrm{exp}+\beta_3\mathrm{exp}^2+\varepsilon$. Why is it so common to put the squared term in there? Here's a quote from my book:

> It often makes sense to add quadratic terms of any significant variables to a model.

Why is that? And if this is true, then if I'm studying endogeneity and a quadratic variable isn't in there is it likely to be that case the the squared term is endogenous if it's omitted?

Comment: Well, for starters, frequently relationships are not linear. Unless I had *a priori* reason to, I'd usually only do it if the residual analysis suggested the linear model was clearly inadequate. On the other hand if I had no *a priori* sense of what form the relationship might take I'd fit something more general from the outset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Often the relationship between y and x is nonlinear. There are a variety of solutions. One solution is to add polynomial terms and the first one to look at is usually $x^2$. But you should first look at a scatterplot of x and y; you should also look at the residuals from the linear model without the quadratic term. But it turns out that many relationships are pretty well fit by $y \sim b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2$ (plus any other x variables, of course).

It is also possible to add cubic, quartic and even higher order terms, but such models quickly become hard to interpret. Another possibility is to look at a spline regression.

I don't really understand your last bit about endogeneity. A variable can be endogenous or exogenous to a model, but that doesn't seem to relate to this ... at least, not in a way that's clear to me.

Comment: I can see why you would be confused. I appologize for that, but a friend explained it to me. Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: Adding arbitrary polynomials to "account for nonlinearity" is almost as arbitrary as asserting linearity. Best to use a nonparametric smoothing regression in the absence of explicit theory regarding functional relationship, right? And if a parametric estimate is needed, following that with an algorithmically determined  fractional polynomial, or appropriate custom nonlinear least squares, or something similar second, yes? A quadratic or cubic function generally does a poor job of representing linear threshhold or saturation effects, for example.

Comment: Let me try asking how I interpreted his bit about endogeneity: suppose that the true relationship is quadratic, but we omit the quadratic term. Do we now have an endogeneity problem?